# python with csv schedule

Tags: python, csv

So, 1st of all im new in python.
I'm trying to do a script that reads a csv file with a schedule and tell you who's working right now.

file:

```
    ;;;;;;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;;;;;;;
Person Name;;;;;;A;DS;DS;C;C;C;C;C;DS;DS;B;DS;B;B;B;B;B;DS;B;B;B;B;DS;DS;A;A;A;A;A;DS;;;;;;;
```

what i have atm:

```
    import csv
import datetime

with open (input('CSV file path!'), 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    turno = []

    for row in csv_reader:
        turno = row[datetime.datetime.now().day]

        print (turno)
```

I don't know how to do it, i feell like i have averything wrong. Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: Did you run your code?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com) Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: your file content doesn't correspond to a csv file. Please provide a *real* example.

Comment: What exactly does your csv contains ?

Comment: there, i just copied the real file. sorry

Comment: The file you posted, contains one header for two columns ? Am I right ? Or you have an empty header ?

Comment: What is `Person Name` and what are `A;DS;DS` and `3;4;5` ? If you make us understand the context, we'll be able to help you better

Comment: sorry, its a schedule, 1,2,3,4 are the days of the month. A, B, C and DS are the codes for time schedule.

Comment: I'm still somewhat in the dark as to what you want, but I can tell you is that given your csv file your delimiter should be `delimiter=';'`. As for the rest, what is the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks a bit odd. Perhaps simplify it.

With your data in a file called timesheet.txt:

```
    ;;;;;;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;;;;;;;
Person Name;;;;;;A;DS;DS;C;C;C;C;C;DS;DS;B;DS;B;B;B;B;B;DS;B;B;B;B;DS;DS;A;A;A;A;A;DS;;;;;;;
```

This will read the data in produce a useful output:

```
with open('timesheet.txt', 'r') as file:

    # read each line in and label them
    days = next(file).strip().split(';')
    persons = next(file).strip().split(';')

    for i in range(len(days)):
        if days[i]: print("Day: %s, Person: %s" % (days[i], persons[i]))
```